# RDLC Sum Only Grouped Value

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, report, rdlc

I have the data from the database in the following format

```
   Name   Amount  Price
    A      100     30
    A      100     50
    C      100     60
    --------------------------
    Total  300
```

Now I set Name as Parent Row Group
And Amount As Child Group
To Have This Format

```
   Name   Amount  Price
    A      100     30
                   50
    C      100     60
    --------------------------
    Total  300
```

But The Total Is Still 300,
How i Can make it Sum Only Rows That Showing To Give Me Amount 200

I Use This Expression

```
=RunningValue(Fields!check_net.Value,Sum,"Tablix1")

And I Also Tried 

=Sum(Fields!check_net.Value)
```

But They Both Gave me Value 300

Sorry for my bad English, And Thanks

Comment: in this case, you show two entries for A at 100 which is 200 + C at 100 = 300.  Showing your original data table content, possible query might help.  Is the 100 value of "A" already a total? and you are getting a double total?  Maybe you need MAX( value ) per group instead of SUM?

Comment: Is Name column a Primary Key?  With a database a Primary key can only contains one entry.  You have two entries for "A".  So how can you tell which is the latest value?  Is there a Date Column you can use to get latest value?

Comment: @DRapp no max will not work , i have edit the post above ( table )  to make my question clear a bit

Comment: @jdweng no name is not primary key, i edited the table above in question, maybe it  will explain my problem more,

Comment: You need to modify the CommandText to group items.  I think the Price column should be Total Price so A give [(100 * 30) + (100 * 50)] and C = 100 * 60.  Or you can display average Price.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this.. I have same issues while group sum.

Answer (score 1):

The expression for the Total should be:

```
=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value,"Name")
```

Here, `Name` is the scope as you are grouping data by the Name field of the data set.